# How to show only some fields on web service result?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, linq, web-services

I have a web service in asp.net and I have this model to return:

```
[Seriazable]
public class Package {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string List<Document> Documents { get; set; }

    public Package() { }
}
```

And in my web service I have these methods:

```
[WebMethod]
public Package GetPackage(int Id);


[WebMethod]
public List<Package> FindPackage();
```

The first method is ok (all properties are returned and it works fine), but the on second method I don't want to expose Documents property, only the Id and Name... how can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want the consuming client to have access to the documents, you should create a separate view model<sup>1</sup> class for the second method to serve. Something like this:

```
public class SimplePackageViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can then instantiate objects of this class using some mapping utility, for example [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/), and return those instead:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<SimplePackageViewModel> FindPackage();
[WebMethod]
public Package GetPackage(int id);
```

[Karel Frajtak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325322/karel-frajtak) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028251/38055) you use a similar view model object also for the package, but since they are identical that will only clutter your code - as long as the `Package` is a simple POCO, there is no need for an extra class. However, if you are using some O/R-mapper that keeps track of `Package` instances, it is wise not to expose them to the client app. Then you should instead do what Karel suggested, and create a POCO view model class for the `Package` as well.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Some call them Data Transfer Objects (DTO). I call them View Models. I bet there are ten other names out there too - for all practical purposes, they are the same.

Comment: Thanks Tomas Lycken, Actually, I know how to apply DTO (or ViewModel) but I think there was a way to do without these objects. My class is not mapped with ORM tool! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Create data transfer objects only with the properties needed.

The first method will return `PackageDTO` that will be 1:1 with `Package`.
The second one will return `PackageLightDTO` that will only contain `Id` and `Name` property.

Answer (score 0):

I would change my approach to something like this:

```
[Seriazable]
public class Package {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Package() { }
}


[Seriazable]
public class PrivatePackage : Package{

    public string List<Document> Documents { get; set; }

}


[Seriazable]
public class PublicPackage : Package {


}


[WebMethod]
public Package GetPackage(int Id);

[WebMethod]
public PublicPackage GetPublicPackage(int Id);

[WebMethod]
public PrivatePackage GetPublicPackage(int Id);


[WebMethod]
public List<PrivatePackage> FindPrivatePackage();

[WebMethod]
public List<PublicPackage> FindPublicPackage();
```

Comment: This still exposes the `Documents` property on the list of packages if the client consumes the wrong method.

Comment: so if he doesn't want the documets exposed on package at all just remove the contract...